# Best .NET comm component or protocol for very low bandwidth communication?

Tags: .net, communication, tcp

What's the best .NET communication component or protocol for very low bandwidth and intermittently connected communication (i.e.: < 10 kilobits/sec)?

Comment: on which level of the protocol stack?

Comment: Please, be specific about the task you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `System.Net.Sockets.`**`Socket`**. There is also a `TcpClient` and `UdpClient` in that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a Socket and TCP/IP for the connection a very low overhead and friendly serialization format is protocoll buffers, a good .NET implementation is [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

Answer (score 0):

yeap!, sockets is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

[RUDP](http://www.codeplex.com/RUDP) looks pretty promising.